# div center alignment using CSS

Tags: html, css

What is the easiest way to align a div to center widthout using position. i have 3 div and i want to set center of page with using CSS

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <style>
        #content {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin:0 auto;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            float:right;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            content 1
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            content 2
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            content 3
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same `id`s multiple time. `id`s must be unique.

Use `class` instead.

Wrap all `content` divs in an element:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">content 1</div>
    <div class="content">content 2</div>
    <div class="content">content 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:606px; /* (200*3) = 600 + (6px for borders) */
    margin:0 auto;
}
.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float:left;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bx5Yc/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use ID like class, you can repeat ID so many times but it's a bad practice.

And I'm not sure if I understood it right, but remove `float:right` from your css which will get your `div`'s one below another. You can see output [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the css with few line of code**

```
.container{width:100%;}
.container div{border:1px solid red;margin:0 auto;width:200px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a width and do `margin: 0 auto;`

Ow, and use an unique id.

Comment: i'm using `margin: 0 auto;` now but that does not work

Comment: Probably because you use the same id more than once. And you use float.

Comment: inline-block won't do it. the div will need a width to have what to center. `width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;` will center it horizontally. to center it vertically you'll need to have a definite height, and to use `position`. The reason your div isn't centered is because it's `float`ing

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are using "id" selector for 3 elements/containers which is wrong.
replace the style with below snippet

```
 <style>
    #content {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin:0 auto;
        border: 1px solid #000;

    }
</style>
```

i just have removed the floating (which forcing your containers to be on right)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap divs with a parent div and add margin:0 auto

```
.wrapper{
  width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:solid 2px red
}
.content{
  background:grey;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UbayUcOH/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify your code as less as possible?

Then you might want to delete your floating:

```
#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    /*float:right;*/
}
```

Because you are using a `margin` to center the element, a float is not neccesary. A float will only put the element out of the flow(so basically the `<body>` doesn't see these elements as his content, which results that the elements cannot center them selves from their parent. There is no parent of the same flow!)

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BH66P/)

---

It is also a good call to not use the same IDs. *IDs should always be unique* 
However same IDs are supported by CSS, but it is a good practice to use unique IDs from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `margin: 0 auto;` on the element which has to be placed in the center. However in order to do this the element must have some sort of a wrapper(not "body") to be able to use the `auto` setting.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page_wrapper">
            <div id="div_1" class="centered_div">foo</div>
            <div id="div_2" class="centered_div">foo</div>
            <div id="div_3" class="centered_div">foo</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#page_wrapper{
    width:100%;
}

.centered_div{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This centers all elements which have the class `centered_div` to the middle of their parent.

Other option is to used `fixed` canter position. For example if you're creating a popup notification message, this might be a way to go.

```
.notification_window{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

But if it's just a regular page element like a div with some content use the first example.

If you need any further explanations please comment.